# How to remove islands smaller than a given radius and specify minimum gap between islands

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I have some data that I have segmented into a number of classes in Python 3.5. The resulting image is the following

Original image

[image]

There are a lot of small islands within the data that I want to remove. I've circled a few of them to give an idea below, but there are many.

Original image with some noise circled

[image]

The idea is that I want to be able to specify a minimum radius below which a noise island should be deleted.

I have tried a few different approaches using scikit-image morphology filters. I have tried combining grayscale closing and opening filters (shown in the image below), and I have also tried using the remove_small_objects filter and treating each pair of classes separately and combining them at the end. They do work at removing the noise islands (shown below), but this creates a new problem. There are thin boundaries between some of the islands, which I don't want either!

Image with grayscale opening applied and thin areas circled

[image]

So basically, I want to remove the noise islands but also have a minimum gap between each island.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

Some clarification on the desired result:
The desired result is to obtain an image where there are no blobs smaller than a certain radius, and also that the thin boundaries between blobs below a certain thickness are filled in or removed. A mockup of what I'm looking for is shown here:

Desired result

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific with what approaches you used with the morphology filters?

Comment: Can you also describe what a good result should look like?  You can even paint one by hand, if that helps.

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt Thanks, I've posted an image of what the result should ideally look like (made in MS paint)

Comment: @Mozglubov I've added some clarification to the post about the approach I used with the morphology filters.

Comment: Those images make the problem much clearer, thanks! It does seem as though you can fix that using morphological operators, though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dilation and erosion (the processes that are performed by opening and closing) are the standard approach for filtering small noise patches, but for long and snaky regions they can cause the issues you are experiencing with the creation of thin regions and boundaries. Rather than dilation and erosion, you can instead try filtering based on explicit connected component size. Skimage has the function `skimage.morphology.label` which labels your connected components, and `skimage.morphology.remove_small_objects` which removes any connected components with size below a certain threshold.

Comment: Also take a look at `skimage.measure.regionprops` for calculating other attributes on regions.